# What would a program that I created in Powerbuilder launch right away on my computer, but takes up to 2 minutes on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, powerbuilder

I created a program in Powerbuilder, and when ran on a personal computer it launches right away, however whenever I launch it on a Virtual machine, it takes up to two minutes before it actually launches.

Comment: This is such a MASSIVE open ended broad question... imagine the sheer amount of reasons why... from your code, to the VM software, to the OS... the list is endless. We can't tell you why. Please ask code **specific** questions.

Comment: I would try running Process Monitor on the VM to see what your program is accessing

Answer (score 1):

Look at where runtime are. If they are in LAN you could have performance problem. Put them in a local disk of you VM